# WebSocket is not open using NodeJs, predender and pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2, prerender

So I recently got an error on my application:

```
Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 2 (CLOSING)
```

And basically I don't know where to handle it. It was throwed only after I made some version updates on my project which uses NodeJs, the prerender library and pm2.

The error is showed in splunk coming from the sourceType=pm2. I don't think it has to do with the application that that is why I don't have any code to show here, but rather with one of the tools I use. Do you have any hint to give me regarding this ?

Comment: It is a server error

Comment: And I don't use Websockets in my project

Comment: This is not a Splunk question, but you may be able to use Splunk to find the problem.  Look for other messages of the same sourcetype.  Consider reverting the version updates and making one at a time to narrow the scope of the problem.